# An index scan is going to the heap for fetching results when only the indexed column is queried

Tags: postgresql, indexing, backend, heap-memory, database-indexes

I have the following test table created in Postgres with 5 million rows

```
create table temp_test(
id serial, 
latitude float, longitude float,name varchar(32),
questionaire jsonb, city varchar(32), country varchar(32)
);
```

I have generated random data in this table using the below query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
random_in_range(INTEGER, INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
    SELECT floor(($1 + ($2 - $1 + 1) * random()))::INTEGER;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;


insert into temp_test(latitude,longitude,name,questionaire,city,country)
Select random_in_range(-180,180),random_in_range(-180,180),md5(random()::text),'["autism","efg"]',md5(random()::text)
,md5(random()::text)
from generate_series(1,5000000);
```

Column 'id' has a btree index

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON temp_test (id);
```

When I try to query with only 'id' which has an index and "explain analyse" the query

```
explain analyse select id from temp_test where id = 10000;
```

I get the following result:
[image: this is the screenshot of the above query]

The execution time of this query was around ~0.049 second and if I rerun the same query (considering the database is caching) I get the results in approximately a similar time duration.

From the results, I see that even if I am querying on an indexed column and not fetching any other column (I know it is not practical) why heap memory is being used when the information exists within the index.

I would expect the query to not touch the heap if I am extracting information from the index.

Is there something I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't describe running vacuum on the table (or give your version, which might be important).

Comment: @jjanes I ran "VCCUM FULL VERBOSE" and I am using Postgres 11 (managed cloud database service from Azure). With no improvements in the query performance. As suggested in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POBmmmFjIe4 I am not sure if I can access the shared memory

Comment: Why do you think the execution time was 1 second? Your query plan says it took 0.049 milliseconds and an additional 0.133 millisecond for planning. That's less than 0.2 millisecond in total. That's not even close to 1 second.

Comment: @FrankHeikens- My bad I was looking at the response time on my SQL workbench.I'll correct my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I ran vacuum on my table

```
vacuum temp_test;
```

instead of running "Vacuum Full Verbose"

Although it worked I wonder what's the difference between the two commands

[image: Heap not touched]

Answer (score 2):

The query is probably hitting the heap to check the visibility ma. Run vacuum full verbose and see what postgres says.. this will make the rows visible to all transactions. Sometimes postgres can’t run vacuum fully for one reason or another so verbose help.

Comment: Certainly not VACUUM FULL.  Not only is it gratuitously slow and unhelpful, it is actually harmful as it clears any visibility bits that were set to begin with.  VACUUM VERBOSE would be a good idea, however.